# Typesafe keyvaluepair enum

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, enums, ilist, key-value

I have a public property on a custom control exposed like this:

```
public IList<KeyValuePair<ControlTypes, int>> ControlCollection {get;set;}
```

With ControlType as type enum like this:

```
public enum ControlTypes : int
{
DropDownList = 1,
TextBox = 2,
}
public ControlTypes ControlType {get;set;}
```

Basically I am trying to create a simple user control that will add a specified number of html controls based on the input of the ControlCollection property.  Like this.

```
<x:CustomControl ID="abc" runat="server" ControlCollection="DropDownList,1,TextBox,5"/>
```

How would I ensure that the ControlCollection value is entered in a typesafe manner?  Or is this even possible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)